# Why does "in the public interest" not use the use apostrophe+s at the end of "public"

Tags: grammar

I belive it's technically accurate to say that

> It is in **John's** interest that the cats are fed.

Where apostrophe+s is used to show John's possession of the interest

But why is is that

> Undertaken in the **public** interest, investigative journalism involves original reporting.

does not use "public's" (i.e. with an apostrophe and 's' to represent possession)?

Comment: ***Public*** is being used adjectivally, like ***the popular vote, the common man***, etc. Specifically, I'd say it's a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) usage.

Comment: And like *bank interest*.

Comment: "Public's" would be legit, it's just that "public interest" is more idiomatic and is equally legit.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Your examples aren't exactly equivalent, since "popular's vote" and "common's man" would not be used (at least not in the same sense).  This is because they don't have noun senses.  "Public" has both adjective and noun senses.

Comment: **public** is being used as an adjective to modify **interest.** It describes, What kind of interest? Public interest. In your sentence "in John's interest" is adjective prepositional phrase modifying "It" to explain that "It" means **interest**. The **interest** is made possessive IN the phrase by the use of John and the apostrophe. "It is in John's interest" is a full clause and can be a sentence with the adjective clause modifying it: It is in John's interest. The subject is "It" and the verb is "is" and "in John's interest" is used as a one word modifier: an adjective. [con't]

Comment: As an adjective Public is not being used as a possessive.

Comment: OP here, please help explain the following reasoning: if 'public' is used as an adjective, then wouldn't it make more sense if it weren't preceded by the article ''the''??

Comment: @Hot Licks: Granted, *popular* and *common* aren't actually noun adjuncts there, by they're still *adjectival* usages. How about *The man on the **Clapham** omnibus, traveling down [the] **London** road* for actual noun adjunct usages?

Comment: @user98937 - One doesn't normally use "the" ahead of a person's name (unless the name is "Donald").  (And saying "in the john's interest" would seem to convey the wrong implication.)

Comment: Consider "in the public's best interest", "in the best public interest", but not "in the best public's interest. *Public interest* is a compound noun and can take an adjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Public"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/public) can be either a noun. In this case it is an adjective, however:

> ### public
>
> #### adjective
>
> of, relating to, or affecting a population or a community as a whole:
>   public funds; a public nuisance.
>
> of, relating to, or being in the service of a community or nation, especially as a government officer:
>   a public official.
>
> pertaining or devoted to the welfare or well-being of the community:
>   public spirit.

---

Additionally, ["public interest"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/public-interest?s=t) as a whole, is a noun:

> ### public interest
>
> NOUN
>
> The benefit or advantage of the community as a whole; the public good.